# Is there a way to watch EyeTV in alarm-clock style "sleep" mode on your iMac?

Tags: tv, mac

My wife likes to watch TV to go to sleep, the only trouble is that the only TV we have in our house is the iMac with the EyeTV Hybrid.   I'd like to have the TV turn off after 1.5 hours of watching without changing the channels/volume--sortof like an alarm clock 'sleep' function.

Do you know of a way to do this either with an EyeTV plugin or an App that might be able to try to detect such conditions and shut down the display?   Right now EyeTV overrides the screensaver.   The Power saver functions don't really work because she doesn't start watching at the same time every night and periodically she will want to record a 2 or 3 AM show.   All I want to do is "close" (but not quit) EyeTV and shut off the display.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with EyeTV, but is there any reason you can't just have the display go to sleep after a specific time?

I believe Macs support crontab, you may be able to use this to have your commands executed at a specific time, but this will only work if EyeTV supports CLI